# Ploting of the two dataset having different sampling rate

Tags: python, plot, sampling, rate

number of peaks I am getting is equal with dataset1 and dataset2 but since sampling rates are different for both data set .I am unable to plot such that its peak look aligned.

I want to optimise the sample without missing the peaks . each peak of dataset 2 and dataset 2 can be aligned.

Comment: Are you able to provide some example data? It is hard to understand what you are trying to do without the numbers or a visual of the graphs you are creating.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12LnRRqu8C6jXineI_7ihhcZAu_U3zTsTQ915wNkK4Pw/edit?usp=sharing          here is example data, I want to get aligned plots

Comment: Can you edit the question to contain the information from that link? Try to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have tried so far that has not worked out for you.